# Is it possible to populate an array in a foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to populate an array of subnetItems with an example item called ted. I have the debugger open and see the items in the array stay null even after existing the for loop. I can see that the currentItem gets set equal to ted but it does not go in to the actual array. I tried initializing the currentItem in the for each loop to see if that helps but it did not.

```
    int startHost = 0;
    int endHost = 0;
    int broadcast = 0;
    int subnetNumber = 0;
    String fullSubnetAddress = "Start address";
    String fullBroadcastAddress = "Broadcast Address";
    String fullStartHost = "startHost";
    String fullEndHost = "endHost";

    SubnetItem ted = new SubnetItem(subnetNumber, fullBroadcastAddress, fullStartHost, fullEndHost, fullBroadcastAddress);


    SubnetItem[] subnetArray = new SubnetItem[this.totalSubnets];

    for (SubnetItem currentSubnet : subnetArray)
    {
        currentSubnet = new SubnetItem();
        currentSubnet = ted;

    }

    System.out.println("Pause");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032235/java-modifying-elements-in-a-foreach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot populate an array like that with a foreach-style loop. You need to use an old style loop with an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subnetArray.length; i++) {
    subnetArray[i] = ted;
}
```

Note: This will put a reference to the same object in every place in the array. If that's not what you wanted, then you have to create a new `SubnetItem` for each element in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subnetArray.length; i++) {
    subnetArray[i] = new SubnetItem(subnetNumber, fullBroadcastAddress, fullStartHost,
                                    fullEndHost, fullBroadcastAddress);
}
```

Comment: Why cant I use a for each loop to populate an array?   Thank you for the help!

Comment: Because the loop variable is not directly pointing into the array, it's only a copy of the value in the array. If you modify the copy, you're not modifying the original array.

Comment: so a for each loop can not be used to modify any item in an array?

Comment: No, you cannot use a foreach loop to modify elements in an array.